# How to manage translation of tags in PHP, Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, localization

I am creating laravel app and understand how to use it's locale options for my Views by using __() function.

But I have something being added from DB. In my app there are 10 tags for posts: News, Updates, Reminders, Events etc.

How can I get the translated name of the tag in my View? is there any convenient method of doing it?

Comment: Translated as in in another language?

Comment: Look at https://github.com/Waavi/translation

Comment: We are using json to translate, we use default words in english but you can use tags if you want.

Comment: But how can I translate it in front-end? Can anyone provide an example of translating tags with backend and frontend pieces of code?